# error when trying to create Object using apache.poi WorkbookFactory: "Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream"

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have excel file, I want to create a report, but when trying to create Workbook object by using WorkbookFactory I get this error:

> “Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream”

Below the code:

```
public void print() throws Exception {

    Map beans = new HashMap();
    beans.put("diffs", getObj().getDiffs());
    beans.put("periodFrom", WsUtils.reformatDate(panel.getPeriod().getFROMDAT()));
    beans.put("periodTo", WsUtils.reformatDate(panel.getPeriod().getTODAT()));
    beans.put("actDate", getObj().getInfo().getRECONSDAT());
    beans.put("userName", getObj().getInfo().getLOGIN());
    beans.put("uvedName", getObj().getInfo().getFNAME());
    beans.put("dictionaryManager", dictionaryManager);
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/templates/reconciliation.xls"));
    XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();
    Workbook resultWorkbook = transformer.transformXLS(is, beans); //get error at this line
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    resultWorkbook.write(os);

    FacesUtils.writeFileToResponse("reconciliation_" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel", os.toByteArray());

    is.close();
    os.close();
}
```

I am also read similar questions in StackOverFlow, but not helped to me.

But sometimes the report was created successfully, I don't know why, it happened 3-4 times.

Comment: What is generating the Excel file? If you run the Apache Tika command line app in `--detect` mode on a problem file, what does that report the actual filetype as being?

Comment: The actual type of file cannot be detected, maybe printing out the first few bytes of the stream in hex will show which file-format you are having here.